# How to compare two values which are structs but returned as interface

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, struct

I am really new with programming in Go and got stuck here.
I have a function A which creates a struct from 3 different values a, b, c.

```
func A() interface{} {
    s := new(struct{
        a, b, c int
    })
    //fill the values in s
    return s
}
```

Now when I am testing this function, how will I compare the returned interface with some expected result?

**I cannot move the struct definition global**

If someone have a better way of doing this type of testing, please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's possible what you want, this comparison looks really "hackish", you should redesign to not require such comparison.

But let's see how to do it. Let `A()`'s implementation be like this:

```
func A() interface{} {
    return &struct {
        a, b, c int
    }{1, 2, 3}
}
```

If you want to compare the result, you have to first specify the value to compare to. One way is to use an anonymous struct:

```
got := A()
exp := struct {
    a, b, c int
}{1, 2, 3}
```

Now since `A()` returns a pointer (wrapped in an `interface{}`), you can't really compare that. Comparing pointers compares the pointer value, not the pointed value. So first we should get the pointed value. For that, we may use reflection:

```
gotNoptr := reflect.ValueOf(got).Elem().Interface()
```

Now we have 2 struct values, and they are comparable if all their fields are comparable (which is true in this case):

```
if gotNoptr == exp {
    fmt.Println("Match")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Mismatch")
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A9W8qR0iVdQ)):

```
Match
```

If you would change a number in the `exp` value, output would turn into `Mismatch`.

An alternate way would be to declare `exp` to be a pointer too:

```
exp := &struct {
    a, b, c int
}{1, 2, 3}
```

And use `reflect.DeepEqual()` to compare the pointed struct values:

```
if reflect.DeepEqual(got, exp) {
    fmt.Println("Match")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("Mismatch")
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pSGONgIhFiV).

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. But could I just return value of struct instead of pointer.

Comment: @IshanSharma Yes, you could, why couldn't you?